# Can we display the p:editor in the dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi the p:editor is not displaying when i try to bring it inside the dialog.how to bring it in the dialog??

```
 <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="dlg.show()" icon="ui-icon-disk" />

<p:dialog header="Content" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:editor id="editor" widgetVar="editorWidget" value="#{editorView.text}" width="600" />
   </p:dialog>
```

its rendered like

```
<div id="form1:editorsad" style="visibility:hidden">
<textarea id="form1:editorsad_input" name="form1:editorsad_input"></textarea>
</div>
```

but the normal p:editor rendered not inside the dialog like

```
<div id="form1:editor" style="">
<div class="ui-editor" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;">
<div class="ui-editor-toolbar" style="height: 53px;">
<textarea id="form1:editor_input" name="form1:editor_input" style="display: none; width: 600px; height: 197px;"></textarea>
<iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:true;" style="display: block; width: 600px; height: 197px;">
</div>
</div>
```

How to solve this??

Comment: Which PF version are you using ? Are you have JS errors ?

Comment: Working just fine on PrimeFaces 5.1 (running on JSF 2.3.0-m01). I just changed the value of the `oncomplete` attribute of `<p:commandButton>` to reflect a new change made after PrimeFaces 4.0 which is `oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()"`.

Comment: am using primefaces 3.3.1 but there is not much changes in the renderer class of dialog and editor ... am not getting any js error ,only warnings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that its unable to load the content because that it fails to pass the condition in the dialog.js-Line No:136(contains in the primeface jar 3.3.1)
 ----------------if(!this.loaded && this.cfg.dynamic) ------------------
in the "show: function()"   .... if that 'if' conditon pass this.loadContents(); will executed and editor component content will be loaded . I used the this.loadContents() outside that 'if' condition am able to get that "editor" component. I am not sure "Why that if condition fails" .Can any one tell Why that if condition fails?????
[image]